# Access follow up intent from main dialog

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am using dialogflow to create a simple bot.
Suppose I have an intent as follow. It works fine if user follow the flow given, where he need to answer like cat first and then answer yes before he/she able to see response of cat picture.

But Now I would like the bot to response in such a way that he/she need not follow exactly the flow given.
For example, if use say i would like to see a cat picture. Then the bot would response a cat picture and user need not go through the flow do you like cats.

Of course, I can copy and repeat each of the follow up intent. But this means that the code repeat itself.
What is the proper way to achieve such scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to achieve this using [Events](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/events-overview), they are used to trigger an Intent.

In your case you define the event (EVENT_ASK_CAT) in the Intent page (after Contexts) and then trigger the event using the the fulfilment (webhook).

If you implement a Java webhook (using dialogflow.v2.model)

```
GoogleCloudDialogflowV2EventInput eventInput = new GoogleCloudDialogflowV2EventInput();
eventInput.setName("EVENT_ASK_CAT");
response.setFollowupEventInput(eventInput);
```

This would be the corresponding REST response:

```
 {
  "followupEventInput": {
    "name": "EVENT_ASK_CAT"
   },
  "languageCode": "en-US"
 }
```

You can also opt to use the inline [Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-inline-editor) editor if you don't want to deploy your own webhook.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Intents capture *what the user says* and not *how you handle that*.

In the example you give, you might create another top level Intent named "Ask for cat picture".

In your fulfillment code, both "Would you like to see a cat picture? - yes" and "Ask for cat picture" could call the *same* handler function. So there is no code duplication - they both just call the same function.